# Does Trump incite more news articles than Obama, Bush, or Clinton did?

Tags: united-states, president, media, scandal

I have the feeling that Donald Trump has received as much news coverage throughout his mandate, as Clinton did at the height of his controversies, continually, since he was sworn in on 17th of January 2017.

Obama and Bush did not appear to foment as many news articles, perhaps nearly half as many news articles as Trump has.

Is there a way of verifying this theory?

Comment: Here's an informal count: Searching for Donald Trump on google, gives 780 million results; Barack Obama 320 million.

Comment: There was a recent analysis and the tone of the articles was also very different.

Comment: I checked "president obama" vs "president trump", it's 31 and 58 million results. It's crazy that Trump makes perhaps 3-4-8 times more news than Obama. That's twice as many articles. If I click on "News" for that search, it's 6 vs 29 million results. Perhaps there is an error there, because of timing.

Comment: Trump was famous before his presidency @MoziburUllah; and both "Donald" and "Trump" are common names/words, so I doubt all 780 million articles about him are true. So that "informal count" is probably ways off.

Comment: @MartinTournoij: It is way off. Adding president helps like com.prehensible has done and the figures are a tenth of what I posted.

Comment: Re: Google searches for news.  Before you leave the topic try Google searches on: private browsing, SEO, and personalized search results.

Answer (score 3):

What Carduus found was also true [during the primary](https://www.salon.com/2018/06/29/donald-trump-and-the-media-the-problem-isnt-too-much-coverage-its-how-this-president-is-covered/):

> The Shorenstein Center at Harvard [found](https://shorensteincenter.org/pre-primary-news-coverage-2016-trump-clinton-sanders/) that coverage of Trump during the 2016 primaries was noteworthy because it consistently outmatched his standing in the polls and his ability to raise money for his campaign. Their data shows that Trump received a full one-third of all news coverage during the primary and nearly twice that of the next most heavily covered Republican candidate, Jeb Bush. He received two and a half times the news attention afforded Marco Rubio, Ben Carson or Ted Cruz.

And while comparing the volume of coverage (considering all media) is rather difficult across time, there have been extensive comparisons between the coverage that Trump got vs prior presidents [during their first 100 days](http://www.journalism.org/2017/10/02/covering-president-trump-in-a-polarized-media-environment/) with respect to positivity/negativity, level of fact checking, or topics covered... all of which varied rather predictably depending on the particular media outlet's [audience] orientation.

Limiting the venues to TV however, again for the first 100 days,

> Looking at Trump’s first 100 days in office, the Shorenstein Center was further able to [show](https://shorensteincenter.org/news-coverage-donald-trumps-first-100-days/) that even though TV news has tended to cover the White House more than Congress since the 1960s, coverage of Trump set new standards. He was the topic of 41 percent of all TV news stories –three times the usual amount – and more importantly, he was the featured speaker in 65 percent of the stories about him.

Answer (score 1):

There haven't been studies on President vs. President, as the landscape of media changes significantly over time. However, they compared volume of Trump coverage vs. volume of HRC coverage during the election, and found he received [twice as much air time](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/trump-gets-way-more-tv-news-time-than-clinton-so-what/2016/09/21/719d1bac-7ea9-11e6-8d0c-fb6c00c90481_story.html).

Comment: For example, news at this exact moment is much more strongly tied to the internet than, for example, 20 years ago. And that means Google, with lesser but still important emphasis on Facebook, Twitter, and some other social media sites.